# Prove that there exists a real number $x$ for which $\displaystyle \sum_{k=0}^n a_kx^k = 0$

Tags: calculus

> Let $a_0,\ldots, a_n$ be real numbers such that $\displaystyle \sum_{k=0}^n \frac{a_k}{k+1} = 0$. Prove that there exists a real number $x$ for which $\displaystyle \sum_{k=0}^n a_kx^k = 0$.

**Attempt**

We have $\dfrac{a_0}{1}+\dfrac{a_1}{2}+\cdots+\dfrac{a_n}{n+1} = 0$, so to relate that to $a_0 + a_1x+\cdots+a_nx^n$ we get a common denominator $(n+1)!$ so that $a_0(n+1)!+a_1\dfrac{(n+1)!}{2}+\cdots+a_n\dfrac{(n+1)!}{n+1}=0$. Then how do I transform this so I have $x,x^2,\ldots,x^k$ multiplying the terms?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Let $f(x)= \sum a_kx^k$. Then $f(x)=g'(x)$ where $g(x)=\sum \frac{a_k}{k+1}x^{k+1}$. Also, $g(0)=g(1)=0$ so by Rolle's theorem $g'(a)=0$ for some $a \in (0,1)$.

Comment: Isn't $g(x) = 0$ for all $x$?

Comment: Here's a real example $a_0=1$, $a_2=-3$, and $a_i=0$ for all other $i$. You can see that $a_0+1/3(a_2)=0$. In this case $f(x)=1-3x^2$, $g(x)=x-x^3$.

Comment: Is it possible the sequence can also be infinite?

Comment: The same argument will work provided all the sums make sense... that is, if the series $\sum a_kx^k$ has radius of convergence greater than one.

Comment: Why do we have to worry about that and not just use the same argument?

Comment: Because we need $f$ to satisfy the hypotheses of Rolle's lemma. You have to be a little careful because a power series is differentiable only inside its radius of convergence and doesn't always extend continuously to the endpoints of its interval of convergence. Outside that interval there is no meaningful way to define $f$ at all.

Comment: How did you know that this power series when $n$ is finite is differentiable?

Comment: It's a polynomial, polynomials are everywhere differentiable.